# 'Pedido_Extra' object has no attribute 'update'

Tags: python, django

I have problems updating the fields of an object that was saved, first capture the id with ped.id and then pass it to get (id = ped.id) to then do the .update and that is the error, Which is tested in several ways is why I need your help please, thank you in advance!

```
def IngresarExtra(request, id_especialidad, cod_experto):
   especialidad = Especialidad.objects.get(id=id_especialidad)
   articulo = Articulo.objects.get(pk=cod_experto)
   if request.method == 'GET':
      form = ExtraForm()
   else:
      form = ExtraForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             ped = form.save()
             ped.id
             ped_ex = Pedido_Extra.objects.get(id=ped.id).update(articulo_ex=articulo)
      ped_ex.save()
  return HttpResponseRedirect('/solicitar/pedidos-extra/')
```

return render(request, 'form2.html', {'form':form, 'especialidad':especialidad, 'articulo':articulo})

```
class Pedido_Extra(models.Model):
    articulo_ex       = models.ForeignKey('Articulo')
    especialidad_ex   = models.ForeignKey('Especialidad')
    fecha_pedido_ex   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True, blank=True)
    fecha_entrega_ex  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
    cantidad_ex       = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    estado_ex         =  models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default='pendiente')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.articulo_ex, self.especialidad_ex, self.estado_ex, self.cantidad_ex)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once):

> Sometimes you want to set a field to a particular value for all the objects in a QuerySet. You can do this with the update() method.

You cannot use `update()` with `get()`. It is a bulk operation.

You can try following methods:

- Call `filter()` with `id` and then call `update()`.
- Use [dot notation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#saving-changes-to-objects) to assign new value to attribute of the object and call `save()`.
- Use [`update_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create).